# Is it possible to send emails from the Jenkins Script Console?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-cli

To automate user registration in a new Jenkins instance, I have generated a `Groovy` script:

```
// Automatically generated groovy script -- 1463047124
jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.securityRealm.createAccount("username", "NGRkOGJiNGE2NDEyMTExMDI0OGZmOWNj")
def user = hudson.model.User.get("username");
def userEmail = "username@domain.com";
user.addProperty(new hudson.tasks.Mailer.UserProperty(userEmail));
```

Then I can either paste this into the Jenkins Script Console or run it through the Jenkins CLI, and it will create the users.

The next thing I would like to add to this setup is the ability to notify the new users their account has been created **via email**. I suspect this can be done, as the "mailer" is installed in my Jenkins instance. For instance, using the *trendy* Pipeline-as-code, I can add to my Jenkinsfile:

```
mail (to: "user@userland.com",
        subject: "Jenkins says",
        body: "No");
```

And it will send it. However, this cannot be reproduced in the CLI, or in the Script Console. Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You could try utilize Java-like code withing your Groovy script:

```
import javax.mail.*
import javax.mail.internet.*


def sendMail(host, sender, receivers, subject, text) {
    Properties props = System.getProperties()
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host)
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender))
    receivers.split(',').each {
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(it))
    }
    message.setSubject(subject)
    message.setText(text)

    println 'Sending mail to ' + receivers + '.'
    Transport.send(message)
    println 'Mail sent.'
}
```

Usage Example:

```
sendMail('mailhost', messageSender, messageReceivers, messageSubject, messageAllText)
```

Comment: hmm I tried it but it did nothing. I don't think Hudson/Jenkins uses `javax.mail` directly..

Comment: Does `mailhost` refer to valid mail server?

Comment: yep, the same I use in the the jenkins config. It's hard to debug the groovy script though :_(

Comment: got this error >> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.System getProperties. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I had to contact Jenkin admin to approve signature. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This script is superb!! works very well....
But I amended it to:

i) call jenkins environment variables to send Build Status in my email subject.

ii) send Email Body with multiple lines as per my requirement like below - Hope it helps!! (added below section in addition to the script mentioned above)

```
def result = manager.build.result
manager.listener.logger.println "And the result is: ${result}"
def environment = manager.getEnvVars()
def body = "Job Name: ${environment.JOB_NAME} "+ 
System.getProperty("line.separator")+" Build Number: 

${environment.BUILD_NUMBER} "+ System.getProperty("line.separator")+" Build 
Status: ${result} " + System.getProperty("line.separator") 
    + " DEPLOYMENT INFORMATION: Check Deployment Console Output at ${environment.BUILD_URL} "
    + System.getProperty("line.separator")
    + " Disclaimer: Please do not reply to this email as this is an auto-generated email from Jenkins"

def subject = " ${environment.JOB_NAME}>> ${environment.BUILD_NUMBER} >> ${result} "
sendMail('hostxyz@com', "jenkins@com", "abc@com", "APPID>>${subject}", "${body}")
```

Comment: I am using .... sendEmail("describe-ec2 pipeline has completed Successfully", "${value}", 'ashish.karpe@abcd.com', ' ') ......... getting error groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: value for class: WorkflowScript........ I have tried '$value' & '${vaule}' it send $value ${vaule} as email body where as I want variable value to be in email body