# Send email from Jenkins job using Groovy Postbuild action

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-2

Is there a way to send an email from Jenkins job using [Groovy Postbuild action](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)? Similar to how it can be done using Jenkins pipeline plugin

```
 mail to: 'devops@acme.com',
     subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) is waiting for input",
     body: "Please go to ${env.BUILD_URL}."
```

Comment: I figured out that there is already similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190055/is-it-possible-to-send-emails-from-the-jenkins-script-console. It helped me. But I cannot flag my question as duplicate because that answer was not accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37194996/4624905 I figured out that I can use JavaMail API directly. It helped me.

> ```
> import javax.mail.*
> import javax.mail.internet.*
>
>
> def sendMail(host, sender, receivers, subject, text) {
>     Properties props = System.getProperties()
>     props.put("mail.smtp.host", host)
>     Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null)
>
>     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session)
>     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender))
>     receivers.split(',').each {
>         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(it))
>     }
>     message.setSubject(subject)
>     message.setText(text)
>
>     println 'Sending mail to ' + receivers + '.'
>     Transport.send(message)
>     println 'Mail sent.'
> }
> Usage Example:
>
> sendMail('mailhost', messageSender, messageReceivers, messageSubject, messageAllText)
> ```

Comment: Got below error >> Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod java.lang.System getProperties. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Comment: Perfect answer. I had to contact jenkin admin to approve signature. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1. Setup SMTP configuration for your jenkins by going  to `jenkins -> configuration`. If you have your own(company) SMTP server that would be great otherwise you can use google's smtp server and your gmail account (you can create new gmail account for the jenkins).
   [image]
2. Add post build action (Email editable notification) and fill the form accordingly.

### [image]

**NB:** Because we are putting the username and password of our gmail account on jenkins gmail will notify you that your account is being used by an app and it is less secure; In that case you have to tell gmail to allow for less secure access follow the instructions [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en). 
If you did not enable less secure apps to access your apps your emails might not be delivered appropriately.

Comment: I cannot use Email Editable Notification plugin. I need to send email by using Groovy Postbuild action